# Can we initiate twilio programable voice call from google cloud functions?

Tags: twilio, google-cloud-functions, twilio-programmable-voice

My use case requires initiating a IVR call from my google cloud function, For voice call functionality i am using Twilio programmable voice feature, I integrated programmable voice NodeJs sample into my cloud function, but i am not receiving any response from Twilio client.

Sample code -

```
const accountSid = 'AC-----------------------------';
const authToken = '---------------------------------';
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
client.api.calls.create({
    url: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
    to: mobileNum,
    from: 'fromMobileNum',
})
  .then(call => { 
      console.log(call.sid);
});
```

Comment: That looks like it should work to me. Have you installed the Twilio npm package to your cloud function? Are there any logs you can share? Do you get a call on your number? Can you add a function after the `then` to `catch` and log any errors?

Comment: I agree with @philnash , it looks fine to me, so I guess that you are missing some previous steps. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-twilio-voice-record) you have a tutorial that may be of help .